# Ask Pandas to delete all rows beneath a certain row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have imported an Excel file as a dataframe using pandas.

I now need to delete all rows from row 41,504 (index 41,505) and below.

I have tried `df.drop(df.index[41504])`, although that only catches the one row. How do I tell Pandas to delete onwards from that row?

I did not want to delete by an index range as the dataset has tens of thousands of rows, and I would prefer not to scroll through the whole thing.

Thank you for your help.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

```
df.drop(df.index[41504:])
```

Drop the remaining range.  If you don't mind creating a new df, then use a filter, keeping rows `[:41594]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can reassign the range you do want back into the variable instead of removing the range you do not want.

Answer (score 0):

You can just get the first rows you that you need, ignoring all the rest:

```
result=df[:41504]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df.iloc[:41504]
```

just another way